# The Chow monoid is an algebraic set

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $X\subset \mathbb{P}^N(\mathbb{C})$ be an irreducible algebraic variety. The ($p$th) Chow monoid of $X$ is given by $$C_p(X)=\bigsqcup_{d\geq 0}C_{p,d}(X),$$ where $C_{p,d}(X)$ are the $p$-cycles having degree $d\geq 0$. It's very well known that every $C_{p,d}(X)$ is a complex algebraic set, but however, I'm not able to find a reference in which this fact is proved. Can you help me?

Comment: There are many references: Chow, van der Waerden, Angeniol, Rydh, ... If you want to see how this compares to other parameter spaces, I recommend the first chapter of Koll'ar's "Rational curves on algebraic varieties".

Comment: @Jason Star Thanks :) Can you give the papers titles?

Comment: Are you serious?  Here is a link to Rydh's thesis -- you can get the rest of the references from the bibliography: https://people.kth.se/~dary/thesis/thesis.pdf

Comment: @Jason Star Yes, I'm seroius. I'm not a professional mathematician. I'm a student who is studying Lawson Homology for his master degree thesis! :)

Comment: I wish you good luck on your masters thesis.